# Using AsyncTask but the app crushes

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask, onclick, ui-thread

You can see three AsyncTask derived classes that are inner to EditProductActivity  class. This class allows me to get the product details when I onclick the item on the listview then I can edit the product details and save it or I can delete it. However, when I onclick the item, the "R.layout.edit_product" layout doesn't appear and the app stops.

The logcat says that: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Further, I try to comment the class "GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask", the "R.layout.edit_product" layout appears but I can't get the product details and when I click save button, the app crushes again. But, the delete function works. So I think it is the problem of the first 2 AsyncTask derived class: GetProductDetails  and  SaveProductDetails . I'd try to search some info about UI thread and try to fix the problem but failed. Could anyone help ? Thank you !

EditProductActivity.java

```
public class EditProductActivity extends Activity {

EditText txtName;
EditText txtPrice;
EditText txtDesc;
EditText txtCreatedAt;
Button btnSave;
Button btnDelete;

String pid;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// single product url
private static final String url_product_detials = "http://192.128.0.101/android_connect/get_product_details.php";

// url to update product
private static final String url_update_product = "http://192.128.0.101/android_connect/update_product.php";

// url to delete product
private static final String url_delete_product = "http://192.128.0.101/android_connect/delete_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_product);

    // save button
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

    // getting product details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting product id (pid) from intent
    pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

    // Getting complete product details in background thread
    new GetProductDetails().execute();

    // save button click event
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // starting background task to update product
            new SaveProductDetails().execute();
        }
    });

    // Delete button click event
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // deleting product in background thread
            new DeleteProduct().execute();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
 * */
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // product with this pid found
                        // Edit Text
                        txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                        txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                        txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                        // display product data in EditText
                        txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                        txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                        txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                    }else{
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
 * */
class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Saving product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // getting updated data from EditTexts
        String name = txtName.getText().toString();
        String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));

        // sending modified data through http request
        // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check json success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully updated
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to update product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

/*****************************************************************
 * Background Async Task to Delete Product
 * */
class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Product...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Deleting product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_delete_product, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // product successfully deleted
                // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Am I using UI widgets from AsyncTask background thread so that problem occurs ? If so, how to modify the code ?

Comment: Dear Marcin Orlowski, I think it is related but completely different. Why do u say I make a duplicated question. It asks something regarding the emulator but I'm not.

Answer (score 0):

Thhe problem is that lines of code :

```
// getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_product_detials, "GET", params);
```

The reason of your crash is that this code needs to be in other thread then UI, just out in `doInBackground` and it will work

```
/**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    int success = -1;
                    //Check for success tag
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        final JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        // json success tag
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    final int finalSuccess = success;
                    // updating UI from Background Thread
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                    if (finalSuccess == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // product with this pid found
                        // Edit Text
                        txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                        txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                        txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                        // display product data in EditText
                        txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                        txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                        txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                    }else{
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I wonder where should I move the code if I need to out in doInBackground ? Move to onPreExecute ? or onPostExecute ? or others ?

Comment: you need just __if(success == 1)__ and so on code in your UI thread, you see, because you use UI widgets only there, rest just put out of UIThread and make success as final, that's all

Comment: sorry that I can't fully understand . Do you mean I should delete the code ? or do you mind showing me how's the correct doInBackground method should look like. Thank you so much

Comment: and all the code inside doInBackground's try{ } , is inter-related. I can't just modify 2 lines of code, instead, I have to modify the whole code inside try{ }. Unfortunately, I don't have idea

Comment: I've edited my answer, sorry for formatting, but i hope you'll get the point

Comment: I noticed that you try to exclude some codes from the runOnUiThread method and shorten the code in try{ }catch block. But I'm sorry that it seems can't work. It creates other problem. For example, 1. Variable 'params' is already defined in the scope (List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();) 2. Cannot resolve symbol 'json' (JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT);)  3. Unhandled exception:org.json.JSONException (JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0); | txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME)); | txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE) etc)

Comment: i don't know about "params" because they'are initializing only once in ,y code, and, ofcourse you need to mark json as __final__, because you're using it in other thread

Comment: Thank you ! how about the Unhandled exception:org.json.JSONException ? I know that it is becasue they are out of the try { } catch block so that problem arises. But if I put everything inside the try {} catch block, then the code remain the same as I post.

Comment: No, you see, you need try catch just for 
                        __JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array__

                        __JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);__ I don't think you understood correctly main issue. The reason was that you were calling __jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_product_detials, "GET", params);__ in UI thread, runOnUiThread(new Runnable().... and you can't do it in UI thread, so i've putted it into doInBackground, try catch thpse two lines, that's all